# Why is my PHP code not getting executed?

Tags: wordpress, curl

I am using WordPress. I have created i.php file (API for sms):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
//Variables to POST
$user = "xxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxx";
$mobiles = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['msg'];
$sender = $_POST['sender'];

//Initialize CURL data to send via POST to the API
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://182.18.172.239/sendhttp.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
          array('user' => $user,
                'password' => $password,
                'mobiles' => $mobiles,
                'message' => $message,
                'sender' => $sender)
          );

//Execute CURL command and return into variable $result
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//Do stuff
echo "MESSAGE SENT TO $mobiles FROM $sender. SMS delivery make take upto 10 minutes. If still not getting delivered please send it again. DND or NDNC subscribers will not receive the SMS. To deactivate DND, send STOP DND to 1909";
}
?>
<br><br><br>
<form name='sms' action='' method='post'>
Phone number<br/><input type='text' name='phone' value='' maxlength=12/>
<br/>
Sender ID (from) <br/><input type='text' name='sender' value='' maxlength=15/>
<br/>
Message : <br/><textarea rows=5 cols=30 name='msg'></textarea>
<br/>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send'>
</form>
```

I have included this file (i.php) in my WP theme's sidebar.php by adding this line in sidebar.php

```
//Including i.php
include_once('i.php');
```

Then I visited my site and see that only HTML is getting executed, not PHP, see it on http://androsocial.com/note3

cURL is enabled in my server.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the beginning of the file i.php

```
require('../../../wp-load.php');
```

Comment: hi :)
That didnt work. My wordpress dir is /home/msociali/public_html/note3.
So I added
require('../../../../wp-load.php);
but it gave this error
 Warning: require(../../../../wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/msociali/public_html/note3/wp-content/themes/World/i.php on line 2

Comment: @user2883925 what happens if you paste your code directly in sidebar.php?

Comment: @user2883925 use exact code I wrote to you. You dont need extra ../